# Endeca initialize_services.bat error

Tags: endeca

I'm trying to create a sample application in endeca. When i run the `initailze_services.bat` I'm getting the following error log.

```
[01.30.15 11:54:07] SEVERE: Caught an exception while checking provisioning.

Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.EacCommunicationException
    com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.application.Application setDefinition - Caught exception while defining application 'ATGen'.
Caused by com.endeca.eac.client.EACFault sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl newInstance0 - null
Failure to initialize EAC application.
```

I tried solving this issue by deleting the state folder in platform services  and then running it again. But still the same issue persists. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that both your Platform Service and Tools and Framework Service are running?

Comment: @chindhuja, please accept the below answer if that helped.

Answer (score 2):

EACCommunicationException can mean a few things:

- The EAC Central Server isn't running (fixed by ensuring that you've successfully started all Endeca services (Platform Services and Tools and Frameworks)
- EAC Central Server is running, but couldn't be reached (fixed by ensuring you have the correct port and hostname specified for eacHost and eacPort in config/scripts/AppConfig.xml, and that you have no firewall rules blocking communication with EAC Central Server)